# Crear trigger para sincronizar 2 tablas con mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Necesito crear un trigger que mantenga sincronizadas 2 tablas:

```
Pieza (codiP, nom_pieza, peso)
```

Y la tabla de seguridad:

```
PSeg (cSeg, nomSeg, pSeg)
```

Me piden realizar un trigger para mantener una copia exacta de la tabla “Pieza" en la tabla “PSeg”.

Estoy intentando algo esto pero no funciona:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_pieza AFTER INSERT ON Pieza
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO PSeg (cSeg, nomSeg, pSeg) VALUES (new.codiP, new.nom_pieza, new.peso);
END
```

Alguna idea de cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias!

Comment: Buenas retorna algun error al insertar en la tabla pieza?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente todo esta bien, cual es el error: No necesitas usar un bloque de `BEGIN END`, ya que es una sola instrucción las que estas ejecutando.

quedaría así:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_pieza
 AFTER INSERT ON Pieza
 FOR EACH ROW
     INSERT INTO PSeg (cSeg, nomSeg, pSeg) VALUES (new.codiP,new.nom_pieza, new.peso);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta que para hacer la copia la tabla secundaria debe tener la misma estructura y tipo de datos.
Te paso un test hecho segun tu ejemplo:

```
create table Pieza (codiP integer primary key auto_increment, nom_pieza varchar(100), peso double);

create table PiezaJN (codiP integer, nom_pieza varchar(100), peso double);
```

Se crearon las tablas y procedemos a crear el trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER PiezaJN_trigger AFTER INSERT ON Pieza
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO PiezaJN VALUES (new.codiP, new.nom_pieza, new.peso);
END;
```

Hacemos una insercion de prueba

```
INSERT INTO Pieza values(1, 'Pieza 1', 3.5);
```

Finalmente hacemos la consulta a la tabla de JN (journal)

```
SELECT * FROM PiezaJN;
```

Que debe retornar esto:

```
codiP   nom_pieza   peso
1        Pieza 1    3.5
```

En el caso que quieras controlar tambien si se modifica la informacion de tu tabla Pieza debes crear otro triger con el metodo after update

```
CREATE TRIGGER PiezaJN_UPD_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON Pieza
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO PiezaJN VALUES (old.codiP, old.nom_pieza, old.peso);
    END;
```

Con esto guardas como estaba anterior al cambio.

Comment: Te aclaro que en el insert no es necesario poner el codiP ya que es autoincremental.